# change keyboard layout ctrl+#

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I need 3 different keyboard language layouts, so in Windows I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

I can not do that in Linux, I currently change layouts with caps lock for **English**, and right windows key to switch layouts if I want **Ukrainian** and **Russian**.

I'm asking if I could, for example, write a bash script to change between layouts, or install a program for key binding?

I have tried to Google, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

On 12.04 I'm switching between English, Bulgarian and Greek with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> without problems.
There is a package `console-cyrillic` that may be will be useful for you.